# Adding datatype to table columns with ClosedXML

Tags: c#, excel, closedxml

I'm using ClosedXML to create an xlsx-file with some data. In the Excel-sheet I have a table with data. In the columns of the table (not the column of the sheet) I want to specify datatypes.

```
            /* This datatable is created and populated somewhere else in my program*/
            Datatable dt = new Datatable();

            ws.Cell(t.Position.Row, t.Position.Column).InsertTable(dt);     

            IXLTables allTables = ws.Tables;

            var table = allTables.ElementAt(i);

            int j = 1;
            /* The options object hold the excel datatypes for each column*/
            foreach (var c in option.Tables.ElementAt(i).Columns)
            {
                table.Column(j).DataType = c.Type;
                j++;
            }

            i++;
```

The datatype is found and added  in the foreach-loop from an options object, how this works in my program is probably not important.

The problem is that when I add a datatype to a column in the table it includes the header of the table. Since the header is "Text" and the value I might specified is Number I get an error. Anyone got an idea how to make it ignore the headerline of the table and simply add datatype to the columns below?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Since setting the data type can work on a per column basis in Excel it's not unreasonable to expect the same from ClosedXml. As you've found it doesn't work like that however. The way I do it is to define a range that selects the whole column except the header. I've not worked with tables the way you are but the following snippet should give you a direction.

```
IXLWorksheet sheet = wb.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
sheet.Cell(1, 1).InsertTable(dt);
foreach (var column in sheet.ColumnsUsed())
{
   string columnLetter = column.ColumnLetter();
   string rng = $"${columnLetter}2:columnLetter}sheet.RangeUsed().RowCount()}";
   sheet.Range(rng).DataType = some data type;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Ended up doing something similar where I ended up manually removing the column header and added datatype on all the column-cells below.